# Twisted: Mixing ReconnectingClientFactory with SSL and have write() be "reliable"

Tags: python, ssl, buffer, twisted

I'm fairly new with both Python and Twisted so I may just not be understanding things properly but I seem to be stuck at a point where I need help.

What I want to do is use [ReconnectingClientFactory](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory.html) on an SSL connection.  I have it all running, but if the connection is dropped all data sent to the transport's write() method is simply dropped without any error.  The actual method called is [twisted.protocols.tls.TLSMemoryBIOProtocol.write()](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.tls.TLSMemoryBIOProtocol.html#write).

Here's what I think is happening (starting from a working connection):

- connection is lost
- call to write() method ([source code here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.3.0/twisted/protocols/tls.py#L480)) with some data
- self.disconnecting is `False` so data passes to [_write() method](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.3.0/twisted/protocols/tls.py#L498)
- _write method gets to _lostTLSConnection which is `True` and then just runs `return`
- connection is regained but no data sent because it's not buffered any where

Here's the a reduced version of the client:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet.protocol import (Protocol, ReconnectingClientFactory)
from twisted.internet import (reactor, ssl)
import struct

class MetricsServer(Protocol):
    streambuffer = bytearray()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.setTcpKeepAlive(True) # maintain the TCP connection
        self.transport.setTcpNoDelay(False) # allow Nagle algorithm
        print("connected to server")            

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("from server:", data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.connected = 0
        print("server connection lost:", reason)

class MetricsServerFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):
    protocol = MetricsServer
    maxDelay = 300 # maximum seconds between retries
    factor = 1.6180339887498948
    packet_sequence_number = 0
    active_connection = None

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        self.resetDelay()
        if self.active_connection == None:
            self.active_connection = self.protocol()
        return self.active_connection

    def get_packet_sequence_number(self):
        self.packet_sequence_number += 1
        return self.packet_sequence_number

    def send_data(self):
        print ("sending ssl packet")
        packet = struct.pack("!I", self.get_packet_sequence_number())
        self.active_connection.transport.write(packet)
        reactor.callLater(1.0, metrics_server.send_data)

class CtxFactory(ssl.ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self):
        self.method = SSL.TLSv1_METHOD
        ctx = ssl.ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)
        ctx.use_certificate_file('keys/client.crt')
        ctx.use_privatekey_file('keys/client.key')

        def verifyCallback(connection, x509, errnum, errdepth, ok):
            return bool(ok)
        ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verifyCallback)
        ctx.load_verify_locations("keys/ca.pem")
        return ctx

if __name__ == "__main__":
    metrics_server = MetricsServerFactory()
    reactor.connectSSL('localhost', 8000, metrics_server, CtxFactory())
    reactor.callLater(3.0, metrics_server.send_data)
    reactor.run()
```

And here's a simple server that outputs the data it receives:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import ssl, reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

class Echo(Protocol):
    sent_back_data = False

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print(' '.join("{0:02x}".format(x) for x in data))

def verifyCallback(connection, x509, errnum, errdepth, ok):
    return bool(ok)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Echo

    myContextFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(
        'keys/server.key', 'keys/server.crt'
        )
    ctx = myContextFactory.getContext()
    ctx.set_verify(
        SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,
        verifyCallback
        )

    ctx.load_verify_locations("keys/ca.pem")
    reactor.listenSSL(8000, factory, myContextFactory)
    reactor.run()
```

Process to recreate issue:

- first you need to generate your own certs and CA for this to work
- run the server first
- run the client code
- wait for some output on the server end and then end the program
- notice the client continues to try and send data
- restart the server end
- notice the server end will continue receiving packets, but packets sent when the connection was lost are simply dropped

As a work-around I tried implementing my own buffer to send the data on re-connection, but ran into another issue.  I want it to send the data when the connection is re-established and the only hook I can see is Protocol.connectionMade().  However, that method is called *before* the TLS handshaking is actually done so it ends up being caught by an [exception handler in _write()](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.3.0/twisted/protocols/tls.py#L514) and placed into another buffer to be sent later.  **But**, that buffer [only seems to be sent if data is received from the other end](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.3.0/twisted/protocols/tls.py#L411) (which doesn't occur very often in my case, and would also mean that the data could arrive at the other end in the wrong order because a write() may be called before data is received).  I also think another disconnection before data is received will also cause that buffer of data to just be wiped.

EDIT:  added sample code for the first issue.  It's probably odd that I have that `active_connection` in the Factory, but I am trying to make it work as a singleton.

Comment: The thing that you're referencing appears to be the TLS handshake, where data (in the TLS layer, not the application) _does_ need to be received before the write can complete.  Can you please attach a http://sscce.org that demonstrates your problem in enough detail for someone to investigate?

Comment: Well, I see the first issue is a flaw in Twisted as data is just dropped.  There's a buffering mechanism on line 516 self._appSendBuffer being used that I think should be used on line 508 instead of just nothing being done (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.3.0/twisted/protocols/tls.py#L508).
The second is a workaround for the first issue and also shows another problem in the code in that any data sent from inside connectionMade() seems to be pushed into a cache that is only cleared when the remote end sends data (not when more data is sent from the client)

Comment: added some reduced code, but I didn't include any certs (for obvious reasons) so it's not quite "self-contained"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the problem with my workaround...  I was passing a `bytearray` to be written to the transport and then immediately cleared it afterwards not realizing that the write was being deferred until after I cleared the buffer.  So, I pass a copy of the `bytearray` and it seems to be working now.

It still doesn't seem quite right that every call to the write has to be proceeded by a check to see if it's connected as the whole idea of the `ReconnectingClientFactory` is that it handles maintaining the connection for you.  Also, I think it's possible to lose a connection between that `if` statement and when the `write()` is actually run, so it's still possible to lose data.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet.protocol import (Protocol, ReconnectingClientFactory)
from twisted.internet import (reactor, ssl)
import struct

class MetricsServer(Protocol):
    streambuffer = bytearray()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.setTcpKeepAlive(True) # maintain the TCP connection
        self.transport.setTcpNoDelay(False) # allow Nagle algorithm
        print("connected to server")
        if len(self.transport.factory.wrappedFactory.send_buffer) > 0:
            self.transport.write(bytes(self.transport.factory.wrappedFactory.send_buffer))
            self.transport.factory.wrappedFactory.send_buffer.clear()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("from server:", data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.connected = 0
        print("server connection lost:", reason)


class MetricsServerFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):
    protocol = MetricsServer
    maxDelay = 300 # maximum seconds between retries
    factor = 1.6180339887498948
    packet_sequence_number = 0
    active_connection = None

    send_buffer = bytearray()

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        self.resetDelay()
        if self.active_connection == None:
            self.active_connection = self.protocol()
        return self.active_connection

    def get_packet_sequence_number(self):
        self.packet_sequence_number += 1
        return self.packet_sequence_number

    def send_data(self):
        print ("sending ssl packet")
        packet = struct.pack("!I", self.get_packet_sequence_number())
        if self.active_connection and self.active_connection.connected:
            self.active_connection.transport.write(packet)
        else:
            self.send_buffer.extend(packet)
        reactor.callLater(1.0, metrics_server.send_data)


class CtxFactory(ssl.ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self):
        self.method = SSL.TLSv1_METHOD
        ctx = ssl.ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)
        ctx.use_certificate_file('keys/client.crt')
        ctx.use_privatekey_file('keys/client.key')

        def verifyCallback(connection, x509, errnum, errdepth, ok):
            return bool(ok)
        ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verifyCallback)
        ctx.load_verify_locations("keys/ca.pem")
        return ctx

if __name__ == "__main__":
    metrics_server = MetricsServerFactory()
    reactor.connectSSL('localhost', 8000, metrics_server, CtxFactory())
    reactor.callLater(3.0, metrics_server.send_data)
    reactor.run()
```